# UITableViewAutomaticDimension chopping contents of cell with auto layout constraints to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

an image is shown in one of the cells.

The image's constraints are as follows:

[image]

The height for this cell in `heightForRow` is set as UITableViewAutomaticDimension. But the image gets chopped off from the bottom. How to resolve this so that the image is shown fully? Thank you.

output is shown as below:

[image]

Comment: Are you not getting a "needs constraints for Y position" warning? I am not sure if you have other UI elements in the cell which determine the height of the cell, but I think `>= 25` should be equals 25 with lower priority than the top constraint.

Comment: @AuRis there is another element `UILabel` which is 15 on all 4 sides which is to the right of this icon. so which one should get higher priority? icon or label? thank you for responding.

Comment: @asdiu what is the aspect ratio of your source image? (is it square or rectangular?)

Comment: @Kymer it is square image 32x32

Comment: If you want your image view to determine the height, then make image to superview top and bottom constraints with `equals` not `>=`, and make the bottom constraint lower priority than top. And for UILabel either don't use one of the two (top or bottom), or make them lower priority than the image view ones.

Comment: @AuRis I followed what you said. top bottom of icon to be `==` not `>=` from superview. removed label bottom constraint. problem still persists. please refer to the updated image in the post to see how it is displayed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment, if you want a self sizing cell, decide which element (or a combination) will determine the height. In your case the image view has a hight constraint, which means, create leading, top and bottom constraint with lower priority than the top one, otherwise IB will complain about the Y position. Then trailing to your label with `>= 8` or something like that, then UILabel trailing to super view, and finally Y position for the label, either center in Y or give it a top, or bottom constraint, or both, but either lower priority than for image view or lower hugging priority.

here are the constraints of the image view:

[image]

The bottom constraint has lower priority than the top one. The UILabel is centered vertically, so it has no effect on cell size. If you have top and bottom constraints for UIlabel, make sure their priority is lower than the ones of image view ones, or that its hugging priority is lower than image view.

Here is what it looks like in simulator:

[image]